# Am i deleting incorrectly?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

So in class we have to create a code that gets word from file, ignores punctuation and prints out the words. Not only that but it has to ignore copies of the same word, but keep track of which words repeat and add its count to a parallel array.But I keep having crashes towards end of program am I deleting incorrectly?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;

int GetCount(char filename[50]);

int main()
{
    char filename[50] = "b.txt";
    int choice = 0;
    cout << "Input the file name: ";
    //cin >> filename;
    int numberOfWords = GetCount(filename);
    cout << endl << numberOfWords << endl;

    ifstream fileRead;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    fileRead.open(filename);
    if (!fileRead.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "\n Error opening file\n";
    }
    else
    {
        //Buffers to get words from file
        char buffer[1000];
        char bufferBuffer[1000];
```

I declare the arrays here that are causing the problem for deletion

```
        //Array of pointers to words
        char ** cStringArray = new char *[numberOfWords];
        *cStringArray = nullptr;
        int add = 1; //Integer in case a word is repeated not to add

                     //Parrallel Array to integers
        int * intPtr = new int;
        *intPtr = 0;

        //Pointers used to check for repeated words
        int * startIntPtr = intPtr;
        int * checkIntPtr = startIntPtr;
        char ** startCStringArray = cStringArray;
        char ** checkCStringArray = cStringArray;

        //Index of Current Word
        int indexOfWord = 0;

        //Variables for character check
        int i = 0;
        int k = 0;

        //Loop to get words from file
        while (fileRead >> buffer)
        {
            //Add Word
            add = 1;

            //Copy only alpha characters
            i = 0;
            k = 0;
            while (buffer[k] != '\0')
            {
                if (isalpha(buffer[k]))
                {
                    bufferBuffer[i] = buffer[k];
                    i++;
                }
                k++;
            }
            bufferBuffer[i] = '\0';
            strcpy(buffer, bufferBuffer);


            //Actually set it in array
            *cStringArray = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
            strcpy(*cStringArray, buffer);

            //Compare Against all other cstrings
            for (int ii = 0; ii < indexOfWord; ii++)
            {
                if (strcmp(*checkCStringArray, buffer) == 0)
                {
                    *checkIntPtr += 1;
                    add = 0;
                }

                checkCStringArray++;
                checkIntPtr++;
            }

            //Reset Checks
            checkIntPtr = startIntPtr;
            checkCStringArray = startCStringArray;

            //Move onto next space of cStringArray
            if (add == 1)
            {
                cStringArray++;
                *cStringArray = nullptr;

                //Add one to index
                indexOfWord += 1;

                //Add one to intPtr
                *intPtr += 1;
                intPtr++;
                *intPtr = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                *cStringArray = nullptr;
                *intPtr = 0;
            }
        }
        cStringArray = startCStringArray;

        for (int i = 0; i < indexOfWord; i++)
        {
            cout << *cStringArray << endl;
            cStringArray++;
        }

        cStringArray = startCStringArray;
        intPtr = startIntPtr;

        for (int i = 0; i < indexOfWord + 1; i++)
        {
        cStringArray[i] = nullptr;
        delete[] cStringArray[i];
        }
        cStringArray = startCStringArray;
```

Breaks at this line

```
    delete [] cStringArray;
    /*delete[] intPtr;*/
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [mcve], please.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Comment: Let's assume you are deleting incorrectly, the best way forward is to simply ditch the use of pointers and arrays and what-have-you, and simplify your code by using `std::string` and `std::vector`

Comment: This is C++, why are people still being taught to manually allocate and deallocate memory for simple tasks. Have you been taught `std::vector`, `std::string` and `std::map`? Any STL algorithms? If not, it's like learning to drive but first you must build square wheels out of stone. It's *completely* unnecessary

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy knowing how the mechanics work under the hood is valuable, and I'm glad schools are still teaching it. Can you make useful code without knowing it? Sure, but you'll have a deeper understanding if you can make it all sink in.

Comment: @MarkRansom Learn the mechanics by recoding string, vector or matrix classes is one thing. But using raw pointers in such situation, that's bullshit.

Comment: @MarkRansom I agree that it should be taught, but this is not the right time to be using these concepts. At best this teaches bad habits that have to be unlearned (using naked `new` and `delete`, no encapsulation, ignoring existing tools for the job), or at worst this confuses the hell out of the student, and scares them away for good. No-one should be writing this kind of code professionally for this task, so why are we encouraging students to do it? (To reiterate: knowing the low-level concepts is important, and I use them all the time professionally, but never for tasks like these)

Answer (score 4):

Every `new` must be paired with a `delete`. Let's check, shall we?

```
char ** cStringArray = new char *[numberOfWords];
```

pairs up with

```
delete [] cStringArray;
```

Groovy.

```
*cStringArray = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
```

pairs up with

```
delete[] cStringArray[i];
```

that all looks good.

Except...

Let's take a look at that last one with a bit more context.

```
for (int i = 0; i < indexOfWord + 1; i++)
{
    cStringArray[i] = nullptr;
    delete[] cStringArray[i];
}
```

Hmmmm. Set pointer to `nullptr`. Delete `nullptr`. The program has lost the pointer and leaked the memory before deleting it.

Not so good with a closer look and less noise surrounding it.

Note this is only looking at the deletion. There may be other problems in the code I haven't looked at. At first glance, it seems overly complex. This is why the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is so useful. If you cut all the unnecessary stuff away, it makes the mistakes stand out better.